# How to press the first item of a list/table in a page on first page load?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am pretty new to ADF and still acquiring hands-on experience.

I'd like to call a managed bean method only once when the user initially opens a JSFF page. The method is bound to SelectionListener of a table on the page. I need the iterators to be available because the handler does some CRUD operation (below is the code for method "insertNewReturnReason").

I have read this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/jdeveloper_11g_r2_and_12c) from Shay Shmeltzer and I curious how I can do the same programmatically.

Please let me know.

Thank you and Your help is much appreciate it.

Regards

```
package com.asrandisheh.mis.asset.viewcontroller;


import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import oracle.adf.model.BindingContext;

import oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding;

import oracle.jbo.Row;

import com.asrandisheh.mis.asset.model.viewobject.AstAssetReturnsVORowImpl;
import com.asrandisheh.mis.asset.viewcontroller.JSFUtils;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer;

import oracle.jbo.server.Entity;

import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.SelectionEvent;
import oracle.binding.BindingContainer;
import oracle.jbo.ViewObject;




import oracle.binding.OperationBinding;

import oracle.jbo.Key;

public class AssetReturn {
    public AssetReturn() {
        super();
    }


    public void insertNewReturnReason(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) {

        // Maintain the makecurrent behavior
        JSFUtils.resolveMethodExpression("#{bindings.AstAssetsVO.collectionModel.makeCurrent}", null, 
                                           new Class[]{SelectionEvent.class}, new Object[]{selectionEvent});        


        // Get the binding context
        BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent(); 
        BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();


        // get the current row for AST_ASSET table
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("astAssetsVOIterator");        
        Key parentKey = astAssetsVOIterator.getCurrentRow().getKey();


        //Rollback any previously created row
        OperationBinding ob= bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
        ob.execute();


        //Set again row key as current row
        astAssetsVOIterator.setCurrentRowWithKey(parentKey.toStringFormat(true));


        // get the AstAssetReturnsVOIterator and create a new row with default values        
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetReturnsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("AstAssetReturnsVOIterator");
        ViewObject assetReturnVO = astAssetReturnsVOIterator.getViewObject();
        assetReturnVO.executeEmptyRowSet();

        // pre-set values for ast_asset_return 
        Row assetReturnRow = assetReturnVO.createRow();
        Row assetRow = astAssetsVOIterator.getCurrentRow();                        
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("AsetId", assetRow.getAttribute("Id"));
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("AsrtDate", "1395/12/31");
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("Stat", 0);

        // insert the new row         
        assetReturnVO.insertRow( assetReturnRow );
    }

    public void saveAssetReturn(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // Get the bindings
        BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent(); 
        BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();


        // get the current row for AST_ASSET table
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("AstAssetsVOIterator");        
        astAssetsVOIterator.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Status", "Returned");

        OperationBinding ob = bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
        ob.execute();
    }

}
```

EDIT: If I use method call activity as an initial activity I get the null pointer when I try to access the ViewObject for the iterator. I have tagged the line cuzing the null pointer exception just in case.

```
    public void assetReturnInitialization() {    

        // Get the binding context
        BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent(); 
        BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();

        // get the current row for AST_ASSET table
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("astAssetsVOIterator");        

        // get the AstAssetReturnsVOIterator and create a new row with default values        
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetReturnsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("AstAssetReturnsVOIterator");
        ViewObject assetReturnVO = astAssetReturnsVOIterator.getViewObject();  // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
        assetReturnVO.executeEmptyRowSet();

        System.out.println("assetReturnInitialization 40");

        // pre-set values for ast_asset_return 
        Row assetReturnRow = assetReturnVO.createRow();
        Row assetRow = astAssetsVOIterator.getCurrentRow();                        

        System.out.println("assetReturnInitialization 50");

        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("AsetId", assetRow.getAttribute("Id"));
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("AsrtDate", "1395/12/31");
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("Stat", 0);

        System.out.println("assetReturnInitialization 60");

        // insert the new row         
        assetReturnVO.insertRow( assetReturnRow );

        System.out.println("assetReturnInitialization 20");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I needed to add the iterators in the pageDef of the Method Call Activity. So I just had to right-click on the MCA and then went to pageDef and added iterators I needed to the executable list.

Answer (score 1):

Check out af:poll component. In jsff page, do something like:

```
<af:poll id="p1" interval="10" pollListener="#{pageFlowScope.wci.handleFragmentLoad}">
                    <af:clientListener method="resetPollInterval" type="poll"/>
</af:poll>
```

When fragment first loads, it calls backing bean method in which you can now programmatically get a handle to table, find first row, and perform desired operations. The poll component also needs to call some javascript (clientListener) to turn off the poll once it runs on page load. This looks like:

```
                <af:resource type="javascript">
                  function resetPollInterval(e) {
                      var src = e.getSource();
                      var poll = src.findComponent("p1");
                      if (poll != null) {
                          poll.setInterval( -1);
                      }
                  } 
                </af:resource>
```

This is one way to do it if you can't do it with a method call in the task flow, which is usually preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the method to a backing bean and then call that method as you navigate into the page as part of the task flow or by adding a binding Executable of Invoke Action. [This](http://dstas.blogspot.com/2010/09/adf-11g-methodaction-and-invokeaction.html) or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B25947_01/bcdcpal005.htm#sthref837) might help.

Comment: Thx for the hint. The first page is from 2010 for jspx pages but I need to figure things out for JSFF page fragments. The second one didn't seem very relevant. cheers

Comment: JSFF still has a binding layer and InvokeAction can be used.

Comment: The task-flow approach is not working cuz I need to some CRUD and for that I need the iterator bindings be available.

Comment: I just don't find the InvokeAction for some reason I don't have it in JDev 12C JSF 2.2 as tired base on the first link you provided (hxxp//dstas.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/adf-11g-methodaction-and-invokeaction.html). If I use a method call activity in a Task Flow, I get null pointer for the view object, For some reason, the ViowObject doesn't seem to be available and returns null. I provided the code about. I really really like to know how I can pull this off from server side.

Comment: perhaps @ShayShmeltzer can comment at least I hope.

Comment: This is why you should always list product version so we don't waste time making suggestions that don't work for your version. Also, the second link I provided which you dismissed contained docs on adding iterators to the executable section of the binding layer.